# What happened to the flag review queue?

Tags: support

I used to have **hundreds** of pending flag reviews, but just today I see that it has gone down to a staggering two!:

[image]

Is this a bug in the system or has there been a major change? What happened to all the posts?

Comment: There's a reason we just got 3 new mods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The moderators reviewed them all. There's currently just a huge pile of 800 "other" flags still pending. I understand how unbelievable this must seem...

Comment: I must have fallen into a wormhole. I'd better ask [physics.se] what's going on.

Comment: Seriously? How is that even possible?! 0_o

Comment: Yay finally!!!!

Comment: @bluefeet Took you long enough. ;P

Comment: It's because I ignored all of the unicoins yesterday